# Is There Any Reason to Remove System.Diagnostic.Trace Calls from a .NET MVC Production Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, system.diagnostics

I hope this isn't a dumb question, but I am writing a .NET MVC application and I was going to heavily use `System.Diagnostics` during development. If so, I was just going to leave all of those calls (mostly `Trace.WriteLine`), in the application once it goes to production.

Is there any reason (performance, security, etc...) to not leave System.Diagnostics calls in an application? Maybe certain parts of that library? I had heard that with some libraries (like libraries that use reflection) you have to be careful how you use it because you could potentially expose your application to certain types of attacks.

Any thoughts on what I should beware of would be helpful (if there is anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calls use CPU and Memory.

You dont need to remove this from your code, you can disable System.Diagnostics.Trace calls to be compiled.

System.Diagnostics.Trace are ConditionalAttribute.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.Trace.aspx:

> In Visual Studio projects, by default, the "DEBUG" conditional
>   compilation symbol is defined for debug builds, and the "TRACE" symbol
>   is defined for both debug and release builds. For information about
>   how to disable this behavior, see the Visual Studio documentation.

**How to disable:**

> Compilers that support  ConditionalAttribute ignore calls to these
>   methods unless "TRACE" is defined as a conditional compilation symbol.
>   To define the "TRACE" conditional compilation symbol in C#, add the
>   /d:TRACE option to the compiler command line when you compile your
>   code using a command line, or add #define TRACE to the top of your
>   file. In Visual Basic, add the /d:TRACE=True option to the compiler
>   command line or add #Const TRACE=True to the file.

Happy to help you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason why you should look into [ETW](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/08/13/windows-high-speed-logging-etw-in-c-net-using-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx) and use [Eventsource calls for logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/07/09/logging-your-own-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx).

```
[Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Error)]
public void TaskCreate(long TaskId) 
{ 
    if (IsEnabled()) 
       WriteEvent(2, TaskId); 
}
```

This demo event shows that it only gets fired if an active listener is listening to Events for a ETW provider. So **ONLY** if you use [Perfview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) or [Windows Performance Recorder (which is part of the WPT/Windows SDK)](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) to capture a trace, the events are written. If not, the Event never gets raised.

Comment: Nice. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving any unnecessary code in could have implications. First that comes to mind is performance. If those Diagnostic calls use up system resources, even just a little, it could have an impact. It could cause longer running times, etc.

The second part that you already covered was security. Anytime you expose internal parts of your code, it allows the potential for exploitation. It might be minor, but the tighter the better regarding security...

If you can easily remove the Diagnostic/development code, I'd recommend doing so, then testing again before deploying to production.

Comment: Remove from code isn't needed, System.Diagnostic.Trace are ConditionalAttribute, we can easily disable to be compiled.

Comment: If you have to recompile the code anyway, removing the debugging/diagnostic code would end up making a smaller footprint anyway. I'd much rather have cleaner code than rely on a compile flag that another person may not be familiar with.

Comment: You may configure only debug to use trace.  This is your preference